# 2checkout. How to sync Return URL order parameters with my orders in database?

Tags: php, yii2, payment, payment-processing, 2checkout

I have a database, in which user orders are recorded. 
Process:

1. The user goes to the product page on the site (I get the products through the admin panel's API), selects the product, clicks on the generated buy link goes to the payment page.
2. At this moment, this order is written to my database with the details of the order with the status "Unpaid".
3. Next, the user makes a payment and then clicks on the return URL and is redirected to my site.
4. Further on my site I get the data using the PHP GET method. Then, in case of successful payment, I need to change the status of the order to "Paid" in my database.

How can I identify the order that was recorded in the database before paying for the goods and the data that came through the return URL after the payment?

Here is my code of creating buy link and return URL, I dont know about correctness:

```
public function generateBuyLink($code, $qty)
    {
        $merchant = 'merchant=' . $this->merchantCode;
        $template = 'tpl=' . $this->template;
        $productCode = 'prod=' . $code;
        $quantity = 'qty=' . $qty;

        $data = strlen($this->redirectUrl) . $this->redirectUrl;
        $signature = 'signature=' . hash_hmac('md5', $data, $this->secretKey);
        $returnUrl = 'return-url=' . urlencode($this->redirectUrl);

        $buyLink = $this->buyLink . $merchant . '&' . $returnUrl . '&' . $template . '&' . $productCode . '&' . $quantity . '&' . $signature;

        // I get this link in the end:
        // https://secure.2checkout.com/checkout/buy?merchant=250366051775&return-url=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-site.loc%2Fuser%2Fcallback&return-type=link&tpl=default&prod=431956EE48&qty=1&signature=f701a8c816b1e880624ab0ea23d4c17bfdf05c5a843db2d3fcf86c57b32a0648
        return $buyLink;
    }
```

Comment: The details are a bit vague. You mention that the user "makes a payment and then clicks on the return URL and is redirected to my site". Does that mean you are using a third-party website to make payments, like PayPal? Could you please specify if so? Please also share the code fragments for the "PHP GET" and a sample of the redirect URL, if possible.

Comment: @chaseisabelle The "Return URL" is generated by the 2checkout API on the same page, where user makes payment, I dont use any 3-d pary websites. I setup return URL from documentation (https://knowledgecenter.2checkout.com/Documentation/07Commerce/2Checkout-ConvertPlus/Set-a-redirect-URL-for-ConvertPlus-ordering-flows) (https://knowledgecenter.2checkout.com/Documentation/07Commerce/Checkout-links-and-options/Set-a-redirect-URL-for-default-checkout-flows). I use GET like documentation says, no other parameters and in any other form comes anymore. $params = $_GET;

Comment: How you create a payment link and return link?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco, I updated the quastion, please look.

Comment: Show `$this->redirectUrl` property.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco `$this->redirectUrl = 'https://my-site.loc/user/callback'`

Comment: Create a method where you will add `order_id` as a parameter to your return url `https://my-site.loc/user/callback?order_id=2` and parse this id in your action.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco It's works)) Thank you very much! I can not imagine that it can be so simple, I was looking for a solution 2 days. Nowhere in the documentation does it say that this can be done. And even 2checkout support doesn't helps.

Answer (score 0):

The return URL should not be encoded.